# Formal Derivation of Divergence

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The formal definition of divergence I have seen is [image: h]

but I don’t understand how that is equivalent to the formula used to calculate divergence in Cartesian coardinates, 
[image: H]

All the derivations I have seen used some hand waving and assumed that the limit for any 2 shapes give the same number. Does anyone have a formal derivation?

Comment: Do you know the Divergence Theorem (sometimes called Gauss's Theorem)?